# Cython replacing list of tuples by C equivalent

Tags: c++, list, cython

I am trying to speed up an already very optimized function in Cython using list of two sized tuples of doubles as inputs and outputs. To do that I need to have it all in pure C first.

In python somehow cythonized the tuple syntax **ressembles** this:

```
def f(inputList1, inputList2):
    cdef double p, i10,i11,i20,i21,a0,a1

    a0,a1=inputList1[-1]
    for i10,i11 in inputList1:
      outputList=[]
      #some more computations involving a0 and a1 
      for i20,i21 in inputList2:
        p=f(i10,i11,a0,a1,i21,i20)  #f returns a double
        if p==0:
          outputList.append((i10,i21))
        else if p>0:
          outputList.append(g(i10,i21,i20,i21)) #g returns two outputs that are parsed as a two sized tuples automatically
       if len(outputList)<1:
         return []
       #some more computations
       a0, a1=i10, i11
  return outputList
```

The details are not relevant what is important is the speed and the syntax: it uses tuple unpacking in the for loops to break the tuples apart and can append whole tuples using append(), it can also fetch the last element of a list and it can return an empty list. It can also convert the two outputs of g to a tuple.

I am trying to change all the python to pure C to either increase speed or **at least not damage the speed** in my mind it should be doable (maybe I am wrong ?). So as g has to become pure C g has to return one object (I guess multiple outputs are out of the question ?)

My first idea was to use `std::vectors` and `std::pairs` lists of lists become `vector[pair[double,double]]` I modified g to return a `pair[double,double]` instead of two doubles

```
cdef vector[pair[double,double]] f(vector[pair[double,double]] inputList1, vector[pair[double,double]] inputList2):
    cdef double p, i10,i11,i20,i21,a0,a1
    #I have to add the pairs as I cannot use the for a,b in syntax
    cdef pair[double,double] i1,i2,e
    cdef vector[pair[double,double]] outputList, emptyList
    a0,a1=inputList.back()
    for i1 in inputList1:
      i10=i1.first
      i11=i1.second
      outputList=emptyList
      #some more computations involving a0 and a1 

      for i2 in inputList2:
        i20=i2.first
        i21=i2.second
        p=f(i10,i11,a0,a1,i21,i20) #f returns a double
        if p==0.:
          outputList.push_back(i1) #I am now using push_back and not append
        else if p>0.:
          outputList.push_back(g(i10,i21,i20,i21)) #g now returns a pair
       if outputList.size()<1:
         return outputList
       #some more computations
       a0, a1=i10, i11
  return outputList
```

Everything is pure C but it is **3 times slower** !!!
I also tried `std::list` and `list[list[double]]` I am losing in speed by a factor of 3 also ! I use `i1.back()` and `i1.front()` instead of first and second I guess that makes me loose speed too. What is the reason for that ? Is there a better C object to use ? Is is the syntax I am using ? Doing explicitely `i20=i2.first` and so on is that what makes it so slow ?

Especially the syntax of g now seems really silly maybe the bottleneck comes from there:

```
cdef pair[double,double] g(double a, double b, double c, double d):
  #looks ugly that I have to define res
  cdef pair[double,double] res
  cdef double res_int
  res_1=computations1(a,b,c,d)
  res_2=computations2(a,b,c,d)
  #looks ugly
  res.first=res_1
  res.second=res_2
  return res
```

instead of simply returning res_1, res_2 as before:

**EDIT:** I redid everything to benchmark the different solutions and:

-it turns out the list[list[double]] is not an option for me because later in my code I need to access specific elements of the list through indexing

-vector[np.ndarray[DTYPE, ndim=1]] does not work I guess you cannot form a vector with Python objects

-vector[pair[double,double]] is actually indeed faster than Python list versions !

For 100000 iterations the Python version takes **in total**:

*1.10413002968s* for the **Python** version

*0.781275987625s* for the (vector[pair[double,double]]) **C** version.

It still looks very ugly and I still want to hear if this is the right approach

Comment: Just to make sure, you used 'cython -a' to see, that there are no additional python<->c casts?

Comment: Yes the -a looks perfectly fine

Comment: The logic on this is hard to follow, not clear why you are redefining `outputlist` on each iteration?  If all your tuples are 2d it would be faster to use a dense 2d array, numpy would be most convenvient, but also could use a single `vector[double]` 2x the length

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chrisb for your first question if you want to know I am implementing the sutherland-hogman algorithm so you need to reinitialize your polygon on each iteration with the polygon clipped using one side of the clipping polygon but it does not really matter.

Comment: For your second question how would you initialize the vector[double] to be of size two ?

Comment: I did not think of using 2D numpy arrays it looked like overkill but maybe you are right I will add the benchmarks

Comment: `if len(outputList)<0:`? How is this possible? I'd tend to follow chrisb's advice and use numpy arrays.

Comment: it is a mistake it is obviously <1 thanks for catching it. I will try numpy arrays asap.

Comment: I did not want to put all my code so I wrote like a parody of it...

Comment: Creating a minimized example of your real code to illustrate your main problem is a good idea, but it is helpful to make sure it works. That way people can actually compare any changes they're suggesting to something.

Comment: Yes you are right I will update my question and add the benchmarks of pairs vs numpy arrays vs normal Python (I kinda gave up on list[double] as it does not support indexing)